# Apache gives intermittent 503

Tags: apache, apache2, http-status-code-503

I have a apache2 server on RHEL 6 and in the past 3 days I have been getting an intermittent 503 response. Its just a couple in a 1000+ request. I had a look at cpu/mem/disk and all seem fine also i dont have any errors in the logs. Any idea what it could be?

Below is my error log which does not seem to be the issue due to the times being vastly different

```
[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 19899] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[ssl:warn] [pid 1188] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1188] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[core:notice] [pid 1188] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

Comment: What is in /var/log/httpd/error_log?

Comment: nothing that links the above. This times are vastly different